# A function with countable discontinuities is Borel measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded with countable discontinuities. Show that $f$ is Borel-measurable.

One solution uses the fact that A function on a compact interval [a, b] is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

But is it possible to solve this problem similarly to finite discontinuity cases? In other words, $\{f>t\}$ can be decomposed something like $\bigcup_n \{f_n>t\}\cup\{\text{discontinuous points}\}$? If the discontinuites were finite, then just I can order them  so it was possible. But I don't know similar method is possible in countable cases. (It will be good then we don't need the condition $f$ is bounded.)

Comment: You wrote: *One solution uses the fact that A function on a compact interval [a, b] is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.* Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that you're assuming every Riemann integrable function is Borel-measurable, which is somewhat like saying every real number is rational (since there are $c$ many Borel-measurable functions and $2^c$ many Riemann integrable functions).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The solution start in there. $f$ is then riemann integrable, so I can define the partition to be increasing set of discontinuous points $P_k$ and lower and upper (Borel-)simple functions $g_{P_k},G_{P_k}$ and the limits of them $g,G$. And use the fact that for $x\in \cup P_k$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $g(x)=G(x)$.

Comment: Actually I didn't proved the last statement, so there can be some errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with countable discontinuities, and let $c\in\mathbb{R}$. We must prove that $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$ is measurable.

Let $A=\text{int}f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$ (the interior is taken in $[a,b]$) and $D=f^{-1}(-\infty,c)\setminus A$. Since $A$ is open, it is measurable, and since $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)=D\cup A$, it's only left for us to prove that $D$ is measurable. But notice that if $x\in D$, then $x$ is not an interior point of $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)$, that is, for every $r>0$, there exists $y$ such that $|y-x|<r$ but $f(y)\geq c$. Since $f(x)<c$, that means that $x$ is a discontinuity point of $f$. Therefore, $D$ is at most countable, hence measurable.

That argument can be used for any $f:E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is *Lebesgue*-measurable, where $E$ is a *Lebesgue*-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and for which the set of discontinuities of $f$ has zero Lebesgue-measure.

(I'm using the following definition: a function $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is (Borel-)measurable iff for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(-\infty,a)$ is a (Borel-)measurable set. It can be easily shown that any function which satisfies that condition also satisfies the following: for any Borel-measurable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is a (Borel-)measurable subset of $E$)

Comment: This is so great! Thank you.

Comment: I have a question. Your answer can be generallized to for any $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ with the set of discontinuities measurable, then $f$ is measurable. But suppose that $E$ is not measurable. Your proof does not use any condition about $E$. Then $E=\cup \{ f<n \}$ should be measurable. What is the problem in my reasoning?

Comment: Or maybe the conclusion is that if $f$ is satisfying such conditions, then $E$ should be measurable?

Comment: The generalization should be that if all subsets of {discontinuies}  are measurable.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I think I may have found a simpler proof than the one presented above. Here's the idea:

Let $K$ denote the set of discontinuities of $f$, and let $C$ be the set of points where $f$ is continuous. Since $[a,b]$ is a Borel set and $K$ is countable, it follows that $C$ is Borel. Now let $B$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $$f^{-1}(B) = (f^{-1}(B) \cap K) \cup (f^{-1}(B) \cap C)$$

Since $f$ is continuous on $C$, it follows that $f^{-1}(B) \cap C$ is open in the subspace topology of $C$. Hence, $f^{-1}(B) \cap C = U \cap C$ for some open set $U \subset [a,b]$. Since $U$ and $C$ are Borel, their intersection is a Borel set. Thus, we obtain:
$$f^{-1}(B) = (f^{-1}(B) \cap K) \cup (U \cap C)$$
This proves that $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel. Therefore, $f$ is Borel-measurable.